# Keras: Why my val_acc suddenly drops at Epoch 42/50?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using around 27.000 image samples for a CNN, having a very good performance, but all of a sudden, at epoch 42 the validation accuracy drops dramatically (from val_acc: 0.9982 to val_acc: 0.0678)!. Any idea? should I just stop training at the maximum val_acc? It's also weird that the validation accuracy is always higher than the training accuracy.

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
...
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2645s - loss: 0.0120 - acc: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0063 - val_acc: 0.9982
Epoch 33/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2674s - loss: 0.0114 - acc: 0.9971 - val_loss: 0.0145 - val_acc: 0.9975
Epoch 34/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2654s - loss: 0.0200 - acc: 0.9962 - val_loss: 0.0063 - val_acc: 0.9979
Epoch 35/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2649s - loss: 0.0137 - acc: 0.9964 - val_loss: 0.0069 - val_acc: 0.9985
Epoch 36/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2663s - loss: 0.0161 - acc: 0.9962 - val_loss: 0.0117 - val_acc: 0.9978
Epoch 37/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2680s - loss: 0.0155 - acc: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0039 - val_acc: 0.9993
Epoch 38/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2660s - loss: 0.0145 - acc: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0117 - val_acc: 0.9973
Epoch 39/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2647s - loss: 0.0111 - acc: 0.9970 - val_loss: 0.0127 - val_acc: 0.9982
Epoch 40/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2644s - loss: 0.0112 - acc: 0.9970 - val_loss: 0.0092 - val_acc: 0.9984
Epoch 41/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2658s - loss: 0.0131 - acc: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0057 - val_acc: 0.9982
Epoch 42/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2662s - loss: 0.0114 - acc: 0.7715 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0678
Epoch 43/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2661s - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0714 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0653
Epoch 44/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2668s - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0723 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0664
Epoch 45/50
27091/27067 [==============================] - 2669s - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0731 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0683
```

Comment: Could you provide more info about your network and `loss`? It seems that you went into underflow problem.

Comment: I would like to point out that the reason your validation accuracy is slightly higher (or lower) than the training accuracy could be due to the fact that the training set has slightly harder to train cases compared to the validation set but it is good that yours are very close. In addition, from experience, validation loss, is going to differ because the validation set size differs from your batch size. Thus, the difference in set sizes can also contribute to discrepancies (which may or may not be your case). p.s. I could not comment so I'm posting as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks `Marcin Możejko`for pointing me to the right direction.

This can happen at very high learning rates
[loss can start increasing after some epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpfbI.png) as described [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#gradcheck)
It worked reducing the learning rate as described in the keras callbacks documentation.

Example:

```
 reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                  patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```